# is-a and has-a implementation error

Tags: c++

So, I got a code like this:

```
class Fruit
{//some constructor method and instance in here}

class Banana: public Fruit
{//some constructor method and instance in here}

class plant
{
public:
    plant(){
      thisFruit->Banana();//everytime a new plant is created, its thisFruit will point to a new Banana Object
    }
private:
    Fruit *thisFruit;//this plant has a pointer to a fruit
}
```

however, I got an error in the "this-Fruit->banana();" that state "pointer to incomplete class type is not allowed. is there something wrong with my code? thx

Comment: Yeah. Check your favorite tutorial/book on what `->` does. Even though it looks like an arrow, that does not mean that it makes stuff point to other stuff.

Comment: I recommend you pick up [an introductory C++ book recommended by the C++ community on Stack Overflow (click on this link)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). There's a severe misunderstanding of what the `->` operator does here.

Answer (score 2):

If you want `thisFruit` to point to a Banana object you need to initialize `thisFruit` with a `Banana` object

```
plant::plant()
: thisFruit(new Banana())
{
}
```

Make sure you follow [rule of three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three), when  you have native pointer as member though.
Have a read [rule of zero](https://web.archive.org/web/20151006051620/http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/rule-of-zero/) as C++11 is around the corner.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
thisFruit->Banana();
```

doesn't make any sense. You probably mean

```
thisFruit = new Banana();
```

Make sure to `delete thisFruit` in your destructor and provide a suitable assignemt operator though. Or make life easy for yourself and use a smart pointer, e.g. `boost::scoped_ptr<Fruit>` or `std::unique_ptr<Fruit>`.

Answer (score 1):

You must use `std::unique_ptr` or another smart pointer and initialize it with a new `Banana`:

```
#include <memory>

class Fruit {
    //some constructor method and instance in here
}

class Banana : public Fruit {
    //some constructor method and instance in here
}

class Plant {
public:
    Plant() : thisFruit{new Banana} {
        
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<Fruit> thisFruit; //this plant has a pointer to a fruit
}
```

See [Rule of Zero](https://web.archive.org/web/20151006051620/http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/rule-of-zero/) and [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).